# How to serialize nested property without showing the whole object?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have the following object:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "parent": {"id": "bar", "age": 27}
}
```

I would like to have this output:

```
{"name": "foo", "parent_id": "bar"}
```

This is my Pydantic model

Model:

```
class TeacherOutput(PropertyBaseModel):
    name: Optional[str]
    parent_id: Optional[str]
```

Controller:

```
@router.get('/teachers', response_model=List[TeacherOutput])
async def get_all():
    teachers = app.model.Teacher.all()
    return teachers
```

I have no idea how to map just the desired property from the nested object. I don't need the other properties.

Comment: what is `PropertyBaseModel`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  It is a workaround for serializing properties with pydantic until
    https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/935

Comment: Can you also show how are you creating the `TeacherOutput` object?

Comment: @GinoMempin I'm creating this for output with router decorator. Added the method

Answer (score 2):

You could override the `__init__` method of the `TeacherOutput` model, such that when FastAPI serializes your list of `Teacher`s, your model extracts the `parent['id']` from the passed-in keyword-arguments.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Dict, List, Optional, Union

class Teacher(BaseModel):
    name: str
    parent: Dict[str, Union[str, int]]

class TeacherOutput(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = None
    parent_id: Optional[str] = None

    def __init__(__pydantic_self__, **kwargs) -> None:
        # print(kwargs)  # ex. {'name': 'John', 'parent': {'id': 'foo', 'age': '24'}}
        parent = kwargs.pop('parent')
        kwargs.update({'parent_id': parent['id']})
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

@app.get('/teachers', response_model=List[TeacherOutput])
async def get_all():
    # teachers = app.model.Teacher.all()
    teachers = [
        Teacher(name='John', parent={
            'id': 'foo',
            'age': 24
        }),
        Teacher(name='Mike', parent={
            'id': 'bar',
            'age': 26
        }),
    ]
    return teachers
```

In this way, formatting the response is kept separate from how/where you get the actual data. (I'm assuming `TeacherOutput` is indeed just used for the response.). The resulting response would be:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "parent_id": "foo"
    },
    {
        "name": "Mike",
        "parent_id": "bar"
    }
]
```

See related readings:

- FastAPI section on [About `**user_in.dict()`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/extra-models/#about-user_indict)
- Pydantic [Model Signature](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#model-signature)
- Pydantic author's [comment on overriding `__init__`](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/691#issuecomment-515409301).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you could use, which IMHO is cleaner, is to have multiple models as in Gino's answer, but instead of overriding the `__init__` function, you can simply transform the data within the path operation function, as follows:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Dict, List, Optional, Union

# I like to specify submodels too with Pydantic to use the dot notation
# but Dict type indicated by Gino works perfectly too 
class TeacherParent(BaseModel):
    id: str
    age: Union[str, int]

class TeacherInput(BaseModel):
    name: str
    parent: TeacherParent

class TeacherOutput(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = None
    parent_id: Optional[str] = None


@router.get('/teachers', response_model=List[TeacherOutput])
async def get_all():
    """Here you still specify the response model for documentation purposes, 
       but transformation happens within the function"""

    teachers = app.model.Teacher.all()
    output = [ 
        TeacherOutput(name=t.name, parent_id=t.parent.id)
        for t in teachers
    ]
    # use parent_id=t.parent['id'] if you didn't specify the parent submodel

    return output
```